# the closing tag "Window.Resourses" is mismatched

Tags: xaml

I'm new to XAML and WPF, and I think it's something small that I don't get. anyway this is the start of the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="SchoolApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:School.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="ColorListString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Red" />
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Green"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Blue"/>
    </x:array>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FF99993A"....
```

and the error is:

```
   the closing tag "Window.Resourses" is mismatched
```

Thanks for anyone who can help :)

Comment: remove the last slash (/) on `<x:Array x:Key="ColorListString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString"/>`

Answer (score 5):

Change the line

```
<x:Array x:Key="ColorListString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString"/>
```

to

```
<x:Array x:Key="ColorListString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
```

otherwise the array's content and its closing tag will not match...

Comment: unfortunatly I'm still new here and can't signed answeres yet